# Django: How to implement user profiles?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Twitter clone and trying to load profile pages. My logic was to start simple and find all tweets that match a certain author and load those tweets on a page as the user's profile. I really don't know where to start.

urls.py

```
url(r'^users/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

models.py

```
class Howl(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    """
    A page that loads howls from a specific author based on input
    """
    model = get_user_model()
    context_object_name = 'user_object'
    template_name = 'howl/user-profile.html'
```

user-profile.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{user_object.author}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm currently getting an error that says "Generic detail view UserProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug." whenever I try something like localhost:8000/users/

I also went on the shell and tried

```
Howl.objects.filter(author="admin")
```

But got

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

Comment: And you are getting that error when requesting which URL?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key require model object or primary key of object.

pass the id of object whose username is "admin". use

```
Howl.objects.filter(author=1)
```

instead of

```
Howl.objects.filter(author="admin")
```

or you can use this one also

```
user = User.objects.get(username = "admin")
Howl.objects.filter(author=user)
```